# What are the available options for running a ruby app in production?

Tags: ruby, nginx

Coming from a PHP background, I'm used to the model of an entire application being booted for each request.

Obviously with tools such as PHP-FPM, this process is a bit more optimised and it keeps a number of child processes ("workers") running under a master process which are pre-warmed/booted to will handle requests.

Now that I'm learning Ruby, I'd like to know how Ruby would sit behind nginx, for example. It's proving difficult to find a single article or blog post about the various options available and the approaches accepted by the community by and large.

Does Ruby have something similar to the FPM style of serving Ruby apps? Or is this request-based style of serving less optimal for Ruby? From what I can find, it seems that Rubyists favour an application-server type of approach - Unicorn, Passenger, et al - as opposed to a "clean slate, each request is fresh" approach.

Comment: What do you mean hard to find a single article on how ruby would sit behind nginx? There are a ton of them some involve app servers like passenger or unicorn and some just use a standard webserver like webbrick or thin but the articles exist none the less.

Comment: @engineersmnky more of an overview of the available options, with pros & cons for each; which ones are in favour and in use by big companies like GitHub etc, what tradeoffs they all have... something like that

Comment: [GitHub Stack](https://github.com/blog/530-how-we-made-github-fast) nginx and Unicorn along with other fun stuff

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at that

Comment: Booting up a new application for each request seems very inefficient. I never saw a production Ruby application setup like that. Usually an application server like Unicorn, Puma or Passenger is used.